# jquery clone selected options

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I have got a multiple select defined as follow:

```
<select id="options" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

now if I select option 1 and 3 I would like to attached only the selected items to nother empty select element, so from:

```
<select id="options2">

</select>
```

I can obtain:

```
<select id="options2">
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>   
</select>
```

Can you help? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
<select id="options2"></select>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown').on('change',function(){
        $("#dropdown option:selected").each(function(){
            if(!$("#options2 option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").length)
               $("#options2").append($(this).clone());            
        });
    });    
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5BU4T/3/